# How to redirect output in an app run on mono (c#) on Linux to avoid 'Array index is out of range.' when multiple threads write to console?

Tags: c#, mono

In our application we redirect the output in the following manner:

```
FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
swOut = new StreamWriter(fsOut);
Console.SetOut(swOut);
Console.SetError(swOut);
```

Test:

```
private StreamWriter _swOut = null;
```

```
    [TestCase(100, "output.txt")]
    public void RawThreadsTests(int howMany, string filename) {
        FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        _swOut = new StreamWriter(fsOut);
        Console.SetOut(_swOut);
        Console.SetError(_swOut);

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[howMany];
        Container c = TestContainer;

        for(int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(unused => Write());
            threads[i].Start();
        }
        //Wait for all threads
        for(int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            threads[i].Join();
        }
    }
```

```
        static void Write() {
            Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        }
```

BTW. The length of logged string is the length of some NHibernate log sql statements.

Running this test on mono 2.10.1 will result in multiple:

```
(..).RawThreadsTests(100,"output.txt") : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.LowLevelWrite (System.String s) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Console.WriteLine (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0
```

```
(..).RawThreadsTests(100,"output.txt") : System.ArgumentException: Reading would overrun buffer
  at System.IO.FileStream.Write (System.Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.FlushBytes () [0x00000] in :0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Decode () [0x00000] in :0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.LowLevelWrite (System.String s) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Console.WriteLine (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0
```

If the output is not redirected these tests will not fail.

Note: as with many tests which include multhreading not every run will produce errors.

Is there another way or redirecting Console.WriteLine to a file from inside the application?

Thanks in advance,
Tymek

Comment: I don't think you can reliably share a stdout stream like this, but have you tried flushing the stdout of the process often?  Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx for a synchronised wrapper instead?

Comment: @IanNorton Why don't you add an answer with the TextWriter.Synchronized. From my short tests it solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)** isn't thread-safe. You should use **[TextWriter.Synchronized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx)** if you want to have outputs submitted different threads.